# Which is correct: 一 (yao1) or 幺 (yao1)?

Tags: mandarin, characters, number

In many sources I have come across the explanation that 一 is pronounced `yao1` instead of `yi1` when used in things like telephone numbers. For example, my HSK textbooks use 一 (`yao1`), and I have seen it on ChinesePod. [Here](https://www.chinese-forums.com/forums/topic/626-is-%E4%B8%80-pronounced-as-yi-or-yao/) is an example this usage being described. I have seen and heard this consistently over the course of the last couple of years of learning Mandarin and assumed it to be correct.

I was quite surprised then when during the course of breaking down a character into its constituent components for learning purposes, I came across [幺 on HanziCraft](http://www.hanzicraft.com/character/%E5%B9%BA). According to HanziCraft, *this* character is in fact the number 1 pronounced `yao1` in telephone numbers. Further Googling revealed [some](http://dictionary.pinpinchinese.com/definitions/s/%E5%B9%BA-yao) [other](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B9%BA) resources also using this character.

Which is the correct character to represent the number 1 pronounced `yao1`; 一 or 幺?